# Nginx returns 404 not found when access file on server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a server(Ubuntu 16.04) and a user called `coxier`.

I configure Nginx to Proxy Requests. I create a file `etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 101.200.36.xx;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/coxier/iemoji/server/iemoji.sock;
    }
}
```

In this flask project, server receive request and then generate a `.gif` file for this request.

At first I directly I use `flask#send_file` to send gif file about 1MB, however speed is very slow.

So I decide to optimize the request.

- Receive http request and generate gif file.
- Return url of the generated gif file to user.
- User access gif file by url.

I have a question. **How can I generate url of the generated gif?**

I have tried like below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 101.200.36.xx;

    root /home/coxier/iemoji/server/output;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/coxier/iemoji/server/iemoji.sock;
    }
}
```

For example, I want to access `/home/coxier/iemoji/server/output/a3dfa3eb21daffc7085f71630cbd169e/output.gif`.

Then I return `http://101.200.36.xx/a3dfa3eb21daffc7085f71630cbd169e/output.gif` to user.

However nginx returns **404 Not Found**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/ , I find solution.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 101.200.36.xx;


    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/coxier/iemoji/server/iemoji.sock;
    }

    location ~ \.(gif) {
        root /home/coxier/iemoji/server/output;
        sendfile           on;
        sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
    }
}
```

You should redefine root in `location` block.

Then you can generate url like this:

`http://101.200.36.xx/a3dfa3eb21daffc7085f71630cbd169e/output.gif.`